# How to change the range of dates which are shown in datepicker jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

For example, this is an example of how one would show the year and month menus:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

But this only shows 21 dates, 10 up and 10 down (for example, 2002 - 2022). But that isn't enough for me, as I want people's birth dates. So, can I increase that range to, for example, (1952 - 2008), as I don't want people giving dates past the current year?

Comment: Is showing only 10 up and 10 down really a problem? because if we select a date then datepicker will again shows dates 10 up and 10 down from the selected date i.e. if you select 2002 it will show a range from 1992 - 2011.

Comment: @ssilas777 yes, it is a problem.

Comment: @ssilas777, it can be a problem. Not everyone would know that clicking the first item in the list, and re-opening the year `select` will show the previous years. Also, it can be quite a lot of clicks to get to 1950. There are atleast 10 clicks required to even see that year, not to mention alternating the clicking and the scrolling to top.

Comment: @ssilas777 Yes, good point, and also, it is not as accessible for my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [jquery api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange), it says that you can initialize jquery datepicker using the following parameter.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ yearRange: "2002:2012" });
```

I hope that helps.